# Yii : How to add datepicker in order to filter gridview

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Here is my codes in order to show some relation tables data in the controller

```
    $query = 'SELECT `Transaction`.`id`, SUM(`Transaction`.`amount`) AS all_amount, `App`.`packageId` as packageId, `title` FROM `Transaction` INNER JOIN `App` ON `Transaction`.`fk_app_id` = `App`.`id` GROUP BY `App`.`packageId`';
$model = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
    $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $model,
               'sort' => [
                    'attributes' => ['id', 'all_amount', 'title'],
                ],
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => 20,
                ],

            ]);
```

and it is view code

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'packageId',
        'all_amount',
        'title'


    ],

]);
```

I want to add a date picker to view and use it in order to filter GridView
I am new in yii2 please advise me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all install any datepicker widget i.e `2amigos date picker`

```
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
```

in your index grid

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
    'id',
        'packageId',
        'all_amount',
        'title',
    [
                    'attribute'=>'attribute_name',
                    'value' =>'attribute_name',

                    'filter'=>DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $searchModel,
            'attribute'=>'attribute_name',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy=M-dd'
                ]
        ])       
],
    ],
        ]); 

        ?>
```

In your controller in `actionindex()`

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new <model name>Search();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: its just a filter model, you can change/delete if you dont need it...
if answer works for you then please accept this answer

Comment: please share search model code as well ,thanks.i'll do this

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
include: use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;//index.php//grid

</php echo GridView::widget
        ([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
             'filterModel' => $searchdata,
 'columns' => [
                   [
                            'label' => 'DATE',
                            'value' => 'date',
                            'filter'=> DatePicker::widget([
                            'attribute' => 'date',
                            'name' => 'DATE',
                            'value' => 'date',
                            'model' => $searchdata,
                            'clientOptions' => [
                                 'autoclose' => false,
                                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                               ],
                            ]);
                     ],
             ]
       ]);

//controller
public function actionIndex()
    {
         $searchdata = new Model_NameSearch();
         $dataProvider = $searchdata->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchdata' => $searchdata,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the full set of options. The default column class gets taken out so you will need to add that back as well.

```
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
            [   'attribute' => 'taskduedt',
                'format' => 'date',
                'filter' => DatePicker::widget([
                    'model' => $searchModel,
                    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                    'options' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search',],
                    'attribute' => 'taskduedt',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                    ],
                ]),
            ],
```